# Using the FileReader API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, yarnpkg

I am trying to read a local static file using the FileReader API but for some reason it's not reading anything. I am using:

```
var file = new File(
  [""],
  "config.toml"
);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = event => {
  console.log(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

The result is just empty. What am I doing wrong? Also, how will Javascript know where to look for config.toml?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to read the file from the server where the application is hosted not from the client machine.

Comment: You said local. Normally, browser security gets in the way of this. Do you see security errors in the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `File` constructor which returns a newly constructed File, where the arguments are as follows:

```
var myFile = new File(bits, name[, options]);
```

- `bits` An Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, or DOMString objects — or a mix of any such objects. This is the file content encoded as UTF-8
- `name` A USVString representing the file name or the path to the file

It does read the file from the path you supply. So it will read the content you've passed to it, and you've passed to it an empty string.

If you want to read a file from file system you will need to use an `input` element with `type` attribute set to `file` and browse for it.

Here is an sample how to use the FileReader api to read images:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 var files = evt.target.files;

 // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

 // Only process image files.
 if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
  continue;
 }

 var reader = new FileReader();

 // Closure to capture the file information.
 reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
  return function(e) {
   // Render thumbnail.
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.innerHTML = [
    '<img class="thumb" src="', 
    e.target.result,
    '" title="', 
    escape(theFile.name), 
    '"/>'
   ].join('');
   document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
  };
 })(f);

 // Read in the image file as a data URL.
 reader.readAsDataURL(f);
 }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: How can I do everything programmatically? I don’t want to get the file name from the user. I just want to read a preexisting file.

Comment: Imagine a web page which can read files from user file system using javascript. Don't you think that it would be a security issue? I don't think that it is possible.

Comment: Please see my edit. I don’t want to read a file from the client machine. I want to read it from the server where the application is hosted.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client browser so it does not know anything about the server filesystem. if you eant to read file from the server the server need to be able to serve the file to the client,the js code you present in your question is not meant for it

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. Thanks.

Comment: if your server can send the file to the client, the client can ask for it in another words, you can use ajax call to download the file, the file is referenced by the uri, nit just the file name

Comment: Yeah I’m aware of that solution. I didn’t want to set up a web server just to share a single file. Oh well.

Comment: but how you want to serve a file without a server in web environment?

Comment: It’s complicated. The react app is served via yarn and fronted by a traefik reverse proxy. There’s no actual web server running.

Comment: Oh sorry. Misunderstood your question. This is why I wanted to just read the file locally in the react app. But I didn’t realise before the JS is executed on the client machine with nothing running on the server.